# Completely stumped by a Flask/Python 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: python, flask

I have spent hours trying to figure out what is wrong with the code here, I must have written similar functions thousands of times:

```
@app.route('/enter_email',methods=['GET','POST'])
@mobile_template("{mobile/}enter_email.html")
def enter_email(template):
device = detect_Device(template)[0]

if request.method == 'POST':
    email_field = str(request.form['abcd'])

return render_template(template,device=device)

@app.route('/select_channel',methods=['GET','POST'])
@mobile_template("{mobile/}select_channel.html")
def select_channel(template):

device = detect_Device(template)[0]

if request.method == 'POST':
    channel_field = str(request.form['channel_field'])

return render_template(template,device=device)
```

AND HERE ARE THE HTML PAGES:

ENTER EMAIL HTML:

```
<div class="widget-modal"> {{temp_id}}

        <form method="POST" action="/select_channel">



            <div class="row-plain" style="justify-content:center;">
                <input type="email" id="abcd" name="abcd" style="text-align:center;">
            </div>

            <span><br></span>

             <div class="row-plain" style="justify-content:center;">
                <input type="submit" name="Continue" value="Continue" style="min-width:120px;">
            </div>

        </form>
</div>
```

SELECT CHANNEL HTML:

```
 <div class="widget-modal"> {{temp_id}}

        <form method="POST" action="/select_channel">



            <div class="row-plain" style="justify-content:center;">
                <input type="text" id="channel_field" name="channel_field" style="text-align:center;">
            </div>

            <span><br></span>

             <div class="row-plain" style="justify-content:center;">
                <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next" style="min-width:120px;">
            </div>

        </form>
</div>
```

I am simply trying to get from enter_email.html to select_channel.html but a

"Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Error is given...What on Earth is going on here? Could it be a problem with pythonanywhere.com?

Comment: Just a note, this error occurs when the Submit button is hit

Answer (score 0):

Running locally with debug on, I receive a 400 Bad Request with KeyError: 'channel_field' and a traceback to `channel_field = str(request.form['channel_field'])`.

From enter_email.html you are POSTing when you submit which is running the line given in the traceback. As a result, it is trying to get the form data of 'channel_field' despite not having submitted that form.

Submitted forms are to be handled in the route you POST to. So, the select_channel route, where you post after submitting your email, is where you would get the submitted email and do what you need with it, see below.

```
@app.route('/select_channel',methods=['GET','POST'])
@mobile_template("{mobile/}select_channel.html")
def select_channel(template):
    device = detect_Device(template)[0]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_field = str(request.form['abcd'])
        # ... do something with email_field

    return render_template(template, device=device)
```

Comment: YES! How on earth I missed this I have no idea...Thank you so much!